# Smallest large circle to fit multiple different radius small circles

Tags: algorithms, circles, packing-problem

Im after a calculation i can use to find the smallest circle when i input from 1 to 10 small circles of different radius.
I am interested as i do drilling and lets say we have 2 x 100mm conduits and 3 x 140mm conduits to pull into a hole. What is the smallest size hole i would have to make?

Comment: Oh, since the conduits are different sizes, that makes this considerably less studied. For conduits of the same size, you can see http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/cirincir/ for small examples and http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/cci/cci.html for large ones.

Comment: Is your problem mainly with two types of conduits ?

Comment: I was hoping to get a formula that you can change how many conduits and their respective radius and it output a radius of the smallest size to contain them all. I found this website for conduit of the same size : http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/smaller-circles-in-larger-circle-d_1849.html

Answer (score 0):

About your particular problem, I would first pack the $5$ circles as tight as possible, then for the given configuration, try the smallest disk that contains it. For the packing, place the three larger ones pairwise tangent, then place the other $2$ so that either each of the smaller one is tangent to $2$ large circles, or one small is tangent to $2$ large, and another small is tangent to the first small and to a large one ( two possibilities). Now for each of these configurations, try to find the smallest disk that contains it. It has to be tangent to $3$ of the $5$ disks, and moreover, the tangency points form an acute triangle. Once you find such a circle, you know it is the smallest for the given configuration. Now compare the radiuses that you've gotten for each of the $2$ configurations. 
I am not sure this is guaranteed the best, but I think it comes pretty close to the best one.